# How to install R on the Cloud 9 IDE?

Tags: r, c9.io

I have recently started using the Cloud 9 IDE and migrated my code from Windows 7 Professional system. Cloud 9 provides an Ubuntu VM pre-configured with Node.js, Python, etc. I am unable to install my favorite programming language, R, using the set of instructions provided on the CRAN site.

This is the set of instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).

I am unable to get this off the ground and have tripped over the very first step of downloading R from a CRAN mirror. I have tried:

```
somebody:~/workspace $ deb https://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
bash: deb: command not found
```

Clearly, I am a noob when it comes to Linux. Any help?

Comment: deb is not a command, it tells you where the repository is. You need to add it to sources.list try `echo "deb https://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The answer Sun Bee gave below should be sufficient to install R on Ubuntu. You also might want to set up a custom runner to run your code from within cloud9. Go to Run/Run With/New Runner and use the following JSON:
{
  "cmd": ["Rscript","--no-save","$file","$args" ],
  "info": "Started $project_path$file_name",
  "env": {},
  "selector": "source.r"
}
There are other ways passing your code from cloud9 to R, it is very similar to SublimeText or Atom.

Answer (score 4):

Update:

1. Downloaded with

   ```
   wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.0.3.tar.gz
   tar -xzf R-3.0.3.tar.gz
   cd R-3.0.3
   ```
2. Installed with

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install r-base
   ```
3. Launched as

   ```
   someone:~/workspace/R-3.0.3 $ R
   ```

Comment: Were you able to install Rstudio on c9? Or we have to use it in the console itself ?